# android webView inside a tab always fits fullscreen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I need a webView inside a tab, should be an easy task but I spend hours reading posts and testing suggestions and I am not able to find the solution! Note that tabs are at bottom, on top works! I modified layouts, create specific activities and many more. Then, webview still fitting fullscreen! I will be glab to post code if necessary!

Comment: Please post your layout code for webview or the code if you are adding  programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Webview Xml..................

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ab02_bg" >


            <WebView android:autoLink="web" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ticket_text"
                android:id="@+id/TextViewMorTickets" android:textColor="@android:color/black"></WebView>
```

Tab Xml....................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ab02_bg" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hddr" >
        </ImageView>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dip"

            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/BannerImage"
            >
        </ImageView>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"                    
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" 
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"
     />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

java file............................

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tablayout);
                tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
                spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("TICKETS").setIndicator("").setContent( new Intent().setClass(this, webview.class));

        tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

Comment: awesome, really helpful!! this issue was driving me crazy! many thanks!